# What is the line that separates the code in Github Atom Editor?

Tags: atom-editor, text-editor

There is a transparent thin line two-thirds of the window page in Github Atom-Editor, primarily more on the right side of Atom. I am wondering what is the purpose of that line, whether it has any significance or it has different kinds of usage.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing a screen shot I cannot be sure, but I am reasonably certain you are referring to the "preferredLineLength" marker. It is a line that shows where the end of a line would be if it were within the bounds of the `preferredLineLength`

https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/